# How would I use Python class definitions for a C++ project

Tags: c++, python

I'm having long lists of networking class definitions for C structs in python.
What would be the best way to use them in C++?

Is there a parser I could use that exports C++ classes?
Is a framework wrapper like Boost, that is quick enough to use it for tcp connection handling?
Other suggestions?

Comment: This is very much too vague. Could you show some code? It's not clear what a "class definition for a C struct in Python" means, exactly.

Comment: If you have the full type specifications in Python, it should be pretty easy to write your own C or C++ code generator for them.  If you're trying to something else like provide C++ wrappers to Python objects, you might want to clarify your question and give a more concrete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could embed the Python parser into your C++ program in order to load the Python classes directly, or write a Python program to generate C++ equivalents to these Python classes. Read about embedding Python 3.x [here](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html#embedding-python) or 2.x [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/intro.html#embedding-python).